# How to write dictionary to a csv file with one line for every 'key: value' and serial number of keys?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

[image]I would like to to write dictionary to a csv file with one line for every 'key: value' and serial number of keys?

```
import csv
dict = {"(2,3,4)" : '3', "(201,233,207)" : '23', "(176,247,207)" : '78'}
w = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "w"))
w.writerow(['xval'+ "\t" + 'yval'])
for key, val in dict.items():
    w.writerow([str(key)+ "\t" + str(val)])
```

It creates :

It does not creates tab separated columns. I want tab separated columns and also a extra column with a serial number. 
**Added:**
CSV data sheet looks like this:
[image]

Comment: @DeepSpace Please see added portion of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `'\t'` yourself. Instead, use the `delimiter`argument of `csv.writer`.

As a bonus, this code:

- Uses `with`
- Cleans all the conversions to `str` with `map`
- Opens the file with `newline=''` becuase `csv.writer` tends to add line breaks

```
import csv

d = {"(2,3,4)": '3', "(201,233,207)": '23', "(176,247,207)": '78'}

with open("data.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    w.writerow(map(str, (0, 'xval', 'yval')))
    for counter, (key, val) in enumerate(d.items(), 1):
        w.writerow(map(str, (counter, key, val)))
```

When opening the file in Excel or any other spreadsheet application make sure to choose tabs as the delimiter.

*I haven't used Python 2.7 in ages. I hope this does not terribly fail*.